# Why SessionFactory is said to be a client of ConnectionProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, connection

As per [Hibernate Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html), it mentions that `SessionFactory` is

> A client of org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider.

Why do we say that `SessionFactory` is a client of `ConnectionProvider`, please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Because a session has a connection, and connections come from a provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate abstracts the connection fetching mechanism, meaning you can use:

- DataSource
- Driver
- the C3P0 Hibernate properties
- or even your own mechanism for feeding Hibernate with database connections

So the ConnectionProvider plays the role of an abstract connection factory. The SessionFactory requires the connection provider right from the start, to fetch the database metadata or generate the DDL (hbmddl), therefore making the SessionFactory a client of the current ConnectionProvider.